# Will using x-Robots-Tag on a 302 redirect URL from advertising prevent Google penalties when the publisher doesn't support nofollow links?

Tags: seo, links, advertising, nofollow, penalty

Usually we buy ads banner on some website (not with SEO purpose) and we use this approach:

`publisher-website.example` -> banner -> `short-link.example/1234/`

On this domain we have configured a Redirect 302 to our website and a directive :

```
Header always set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

so something like this

```
redirect 302 /1234/ ourwebsite.example
```

Is it safe? Is this avoiding SEO penalties as we are not buying link for SEO purpose? Unfortunately the publisher does not support to our request to add `nofollow` directly to the link.

If it's not safe, are there alternative?